# Finding zeros for $2a + 4bx^2 - qcx^{q-2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials, roots, math-software

Does anyone know a free app or site that I can use to solve the following equation:

> $ 2a+4bx^2 -q c x^{q-2}=0 $, where, $a, b, c\in \mathbb{R}$, $a, b, c>0$ and $q>2$.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those integer values for $a,b,c,q$?

Comment: They are real values. I will add this to equation

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1.2+%2B+3.4+x%5E2+-+5.6+x%5E7.8+%3D+0)

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't solve an equation with a expoent parameter, as $q$. Only for multiplicative ones as $a, b,c $. In the equation notation.

Answer (score 0):

If $q$ can be *any* number, the problem is purely numerical and you look for the *positive* zero of function
$$f(x)=2a + 4bx^2 - qcx^{q-2}$$

I think that I should start simplifying  using $4bx^2=t$ to make
$$g(t)=2a+t-m t^n \quad \text{with}\quad m=c q(4b)^{1-\frac{q}{2}}>0\quad \text{and}\quad n=\frac q 2-1>0$$ This reduces the problem to the intersection of a straight line and an increasing power function.